# Subversion merge fails with "Entry for ... has no URL"

Tags: svn, merge, rollback

I'm trying to roll back a range of commits.  Say my working copy is revision 10, and I'm wanting to roll back all changes made in revisions 4 through 7.  I'm attempting to do so with:

```
svn merge -r 7:4 .
```

This fails with:

> svn: Entry for 'library' has no URL

In looking around on the SO and in the subversion manuals it sounds like this is due to a missing folder.  The suggestion I've seen to address this is to do `svn cleanup` then `svn update` prior to merging.  I've tried that and it hasn't made any difference.

Anyone have anything else I might try, or even some more insight into *why* it's failing?  I looked for a "verbose" option to `svn` but didn't find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I had local modifications to a file prior to attempting to do the merge, despite the fact that I had done an update immediately before.  I reverted the file and retried the merge, worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

- Format of merge command is clean: `merge SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH]`, i.e:

you can skip **target** definition (because . is assumed and it's OK if you are in the root of WC), but must use source of merge

- You can always test any merge using `--dry-run` option *before real merge*
- You can split big reverse-merge into smaller chunks and undo one revision in command with `-c -N`

**PS**: start from p.1 and use URL of you Working Copy as source-path

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't address my question.  I understand how to *do* the merge (syntax in my question is correcct), what I don't understand is why when attempting to do so I'm seeing the error in my question, or how to fix it.